# os.rename() using user input variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to rename a folder, the folder was created by requesting a user input and sub folders created within, to rename the parent directory (asset_name) I am using `filedialog.askdirectory()` but I keep getting stuck with the error

```
TypeError: Can't convert 'StringVar' object to str implicitly
```

I have read all the documentation I can find on `os.rename()` and it always refers to ("path","path") rather than variables, I have tried working the line backward to alleviate the error but to no avail, I'll post the whole error here:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
   File "<module1>", line 59, in fldrRename
TypeError: Can't convert 'StringVar' object to str implicitly
```

this is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import tix
from tkinter.constants import *
from tkinter import filedialog
import os, sys
import itertools
import getpass


root = Tk()
root.title("WRT Project Manager")

path = ("P://Projects_2013//")

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root, padding="12 12 12 12")
mainframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))
mainframe.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
mainframe.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)


prjtnm= StringVar()
Dirlist= StringVar()
in2 = StringVar()
in3 = StringVar()
assetVar = StringVar()
dirlst = StringVar()
fldr = StringVar()
currentproject = StringVar()

#get a list of all the directories
def dirlist():
    from tkinter.filedialog import askdirectory
    dirlist = path
    if dirlist:
    path.set(dirlist)


# create project folder and sub directories
def genAsset():
    asset_name = assetVar.get()
    os.chdir("P:\\Projects_2013")
    dirs = [[asset_name],
            ["fldr1", "fldr2", "fldr3", "fldr4", "fldr5", "fldr6"]]
    for item in itertools.product(*dirs):
            os.makedirs(os.path.join(*item))

#choose an existing project directory
def sel_Browse():
    fldr = filedialog.askdirectory()
    currentproject = fldr
    prjtnm.delete(0, END)
    prjtnm.insert(0, fldr)


#rename a folder 'completed-'
def fldrRename():
    newname = ("completed- "+ currentproject)
    os.chdir("P:\\Projects_2013")
    os.rename(currentproject,newname)



ttk.Label(mainframe, text="User =").grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=E)
ttk.Label(mainframe,text=getpass.getuser()).grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Project directory path is P:/Projects_2013/").grid(column=3, row=1, sticky=W)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Enter NEW project name:").grid(column=2, row=2, sticky=E, pady=15)
ttk.Entry(mainframe, textvariable= assetVar, width=50).grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=(W,E))
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Create Folders", command=genAsset).grid(column=5, row=2, sticky=E, padx=10)
ttk.Label (mainframe, text='Select an existing project:').grid(column=2,row=3, sticky=E)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Browse", command=sel_Browse).grid(row=3,column=5, sticky=E, padx=10)
prjtnm = Entry(mainframe, width=50)
prjtnm.grid(row=3,column=3)
ttk.Button(mainframe, text="Close", command=fldrRename).grid(row=4,column=3, padx=10)
ttk.Label(mainframe, text="Select Date").grid(column=1, row=6, sticky=W)
in3_entry = ttk.Entry(mainframe, width=20, textvariable=in3)
in3_entry.grid(column=2, row=6, sticky=(W, E))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Use `currentproject.get()` to get the string representation of your variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error has very little to do with `os.rename()`; the exception is raised because you are trying to concatenate a `tkinter` GUI object with a string:

```
newname = ("completed- "+ currentproject)
```

`currentproject` is not a string here, it's a `StringVar()` object:

```
currentproject = StringVar()
```

Call `.get()` on a `StringVar()` to get the current value instead:

```
newname = "completed-" + currentproject.get()
```

Note that the parenthesis are not needed here, at all.

You also need to *set* the variable correctly, in `self_Browse()`:

```
def sel_Browse():
    fldr = filedialog.askdirectory()
    currentproject.set(fldr)
```

Comment: thank you very much, it makes good sense! unfortunately if i print (newname) before the folder rename so i can see what is being returned, newname is "completed- " it still doesn't include the 'currentproject' variable on the end ? Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1475, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "S:\python\jon\wrt toolkit v3.py", line 62, in fldrRename
    os.rename(currentproject,newname)
TypeError: illegal type for path parameter

Comment: @jon141: right, you never *set* the variable either; updated the answer.

Comment: great stuff, this has cleared things up a lot regarding the variable, thank you, it seems i have a lot of learning now about path names as 'currentproject' returns the whole path rather than just the folder name so the os.rename() command tries to give the new name of "P:\Projects_2013\ completed - P:\projects_2013\foldername"  LOL! thank you for your help.

Comment: take a look at the `os.path` module to manipulate paths. `os.path.basename()` will remove the path leaving *just* the last part of the filename.